# How to change the boundary color of boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot

I'd like to create boxplot like this:[image]

This plot is created by bwplot in lattice package. Instead using this function, I hope to use boxplot to plot similar thing.

I notice in boxplot we could only change the color of the box body, how could I change the boundary color of the box by boxplot function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at `?boxplot` to find that there's an argument `border=` that does what you want. For example:

```
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray",
        border=c("blue", "green", "blue", "green", "blue", "green"))
```

[image]